# How to "try" to read input in C

Tags: c, console, chat

Im writing a program which allows to chat between two processes in Linux. To transfer messages I use IPC queues.

I have a problem with main loop: I need to check if there's any new message in the queue and if there is - print it. Then I need to check if there is any input, and if there is - scanf it (this is the problem).
Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you block on the queue?

Comment: What kind of problem do you have with [`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non blocking operations. If a `read()` is performed on a file descriptor opened with `O_NONBLOCK` flag, and there's no data available at that moment, `read()` will return inmediately with `errno = -EWOULDBLOCK` .

Another option is to use `select()` to poll more than one descriptor.

Comment: `select` can be both polling and non-polling, depending on how long the timout is. But by default it doesn't return until one of the monitored descriptors has data to read or can accept writes (depending on parameters). The `select` method is what I prefer when I need to wait for input.

Answer (score 0):

to add more value to my post I'm pasting an example I found, which solves my problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);

    /* Wait up to five seconds. */
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

    if (retval == −1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval)
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
        /* FD_ISSET(0, &rfds) will be true. */
    else
        printf("No data within five seconds.\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```